# How do i make my button link to the next page without changing the styling of the code? Where am i getting it wrong?

Tags: html, css

How do I make my button link to the next page without changing the styling?

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="image-round-fit">

    <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="photo" width="300px" height="300px" />

    <span class="caption">Hello World</span></br>

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info role=button">Click Next</a>

  </div>
```

Here is the CSS

.btn {

```
background-color: DodgerBlue;

border: none;

color: white;

margin: 50px;

padding: 12px 30px;

cursor: pointer;

font-size: 20px;

display: flex;

align-items: center;

justify-content: center;
```

}

.btn:hover {

```
background-color: rgb(255,94,0);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-round-fit">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info role=button">Click Next</a>
</div>
```

It is kind of weird that you added the hover css code, because this is the origin of your problem, can you explain why you did this?